# Unable to access my JSP pages deployed on Apache Tomcat 6.0 from internet

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I am unable to find the solution for this question thats why I am posting it here. Please excuse me and provide me useful links if this Q has been asked before.

**How can I access my JSP pages deployed on Apache Tomcat on my home PC from internet**? Following are the configurations.

Operating System: Windows XP SP2
Antivirus or Firewall: Not installed
Connected to LAN: no (directly connected to internet with a broadband connection)
Web Server: Apache Tomcat 6.0 and no other server installed.
IP type: dynamic/not static
port used: 8080

I am able to access it on other PCs if it is connected to lan.

Do I need to make some changes in the tomcat configuration files in order to get success in it?

Comment: How are you trying to access it? Are you using the IP address from your ISP? When you say "directly" do you mean you have no routers, with its own firewall? Can you access anything on your IP externally? Can you ping your box?

Comment: Yes! I am using the IP address from my ISP. There are no routers installed except the wireless modem given by the ISP.<br><br>

Yesterday, I pinged my box and it said that "Destination is unreachable". Now today i pinged again and the statistics says<br><br>

Packets: Sent = 49, Received = 40, Lost = 9 (18% loss),<br><br>


Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:<br><br>


    Minimum = 21ms, Maximum = 62ms, Average = 30ms<br><br>

Now I am able to open my simple home page but not my App. Probably, its due to the packets lost in transmission. Anyways thanks for this debugging tip.